# Webhook для telegram bota на облачном сервере

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, vds, webhook

Как правильно вообще сделать что бы бот работал на выделенном сервере через вебхук.

**Инициализирую бота**

```
const bot = new TelegramBot(TOKEN, {
  webHook: {
    port: PORT,
  },
});

bot.setWebHook(`${URL}/${TOKEN}`);
```

В панельке сервера  есть IP сервера и нагуглил что порты можно указывать **443, 80, 88, или 8443**.

**Конфиг**

```
webhook: { url: 'https://32.171.135.186', port: 8483 }
```

**Так же создал SSL для сервера** вот этой командой

`openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout YOURPRIVATE.key -x509 -days 365 -out YOURPUBLIC.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=Brooklyn/O=Example Brooklyn Company/CN=YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE"`

На команды соответственно не реагирует, но сообщения отложенные присылает. Что я делаю не так?